# Rename error in the eclipse while using the ALT+Shift+R?

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I tried to select the word that want to replace for multiple times and it did not. Finally I had to close the eclipse and start it.**

Answer (score 1):

**Rename (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) is a refactoring** option. E.g. this could be used to rename a class or a method without renaming classes/methods with the same name but in different packages/classes if it was selected.

To search replace words in Eclipse **within a single file**, the replace option is there in the ***Find/Replace*** dialog that shows when you press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**.

To search **replace across files**, go to *Search/Search* (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>**), and look for the ***File Search*** tab at the top (you normally need to scroll the tabs to the left to see it).  This will let you search across a range of files, and then replace those matches.